# Asp.net core Identity "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core, seeding

I create ASP.NET CORE application with ASP.NET CORE Identity. 
I create seed class for saving new users and roles for first startup application. Inside this seed class I get following error when I add Role To User.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_AspNetUserRoles_AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "DB_A14695_Elvinm", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

I used following class for Identity

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Flags { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And my seed class

```
 public class DbSeeder
{
    #region Private Members
    private RvMusicalDbContext DbContext;
    private RoleManager<IdentityRole> RoleManager;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager;
    #endregion Private Members

    #region Constructor
    public DbSeeder(RvMusicalDbContext dbContext, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        DbContext = dbContext;
        RoleManager = roleManager;
        UserManager = userManager;
    }
    #endregion Constructor

    #region Public Methods
    public async Task SeedAsync()
    {
        // Create the Db if it doesn’t exist
        DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();
        // Create default Users
        if (await DbContext.Users.CountAsync() == 0) await CreateUsersAsync();
    }
    #endregion Public Methods

    #region Seed Methods
    private async Task CreateUsersAsync()
    {
        // local variables
        DateTime createdDate = new DateTime(2016, 03, 01, 12, 30, 00);
        DateTime lastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
        string role_Administrators = "Administrators";
        string role_Registered = "Registered";

        //Create Roles (if they doesn't exist yet)
        if (!await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role_Administrators)) await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role_Administrators));
        if (!await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role_Registered)) await RoleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role_Registered));

        // Create the "Admin" ApplicationUser account (if it doesn't exist already)
        var user_Admin = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "Admin",
            Email = "admin@opengamelist.com",
            CreatedDate = createdDate,
            LastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate,
            Flags = 0,
            Type = 0
        };

        // Insert "Admin" into the Database and also assign the "Administrator" role to him.
        if (await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(user_Admin.Id) == null)
        {
            await UserManager.CreateAsync(user_Admin, "Pass4Admin");
            /// ERROR OCCURED HERE
            await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user_Admin, role_Administrators);
            // Remove Lockout and E-Mail confirmation.
            user_Admin.EmailConfirmed = true;
            user_Admin.LockoutEnabled = false;
        }

    #endregion Seed Methods


}
```

I want to say that roles saved database successfully.

Please help to solve problem.

Comment: I am not sure that  there is a difference between two example logic. Second, I must create seed class, as I said above

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check the output of UserManager.CreateAsync call right before the error.  I'm guessing your user doesn't get persisted so the next call fails with an FK issue.

If you are using the default identity password requirements (like I was when I tried it) you get a password validation error result from the user creation call.

[image]

Comment: I was focused on the Exception, which has nothing to do with the problem, which in my case was a duplicate user/email. Thanks for ending my misery, Dave.

Comment: That was exactly my issue. In previos version of Entity Framework it was ok to have test user password 'Password1', but not in the EF Core. I was so sure while creating a user that didn't verify the result.Succeded. That cost me a lot of debugging and googling, becase I had other issue related to foreighn keys contstraints conflicted. Now I know that it was, becasue my user was never created, so passing userid anywhere caused the error.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error but it is saying the UserName and Email are invalid. Please, take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813937/microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanagerwarning-user-validation-failed-inval

Comment: @ThadeuAntonioFerreiraMelo Looks like you got it sorted. :)

Comment: Thank you! My first test user had Null as email, so the second I tried creating had a duplicate email of null. Your answer led me to finding the problem.

Comment: Unbelievable. They bury the real problem way deep in the output window, and show you something irrelevant. I wasted ages on this. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Thank you. Password validation was in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was answered but I just had to add my solution to my problem in the hopes that I can save some other poor soul from repeating my mistake.....

My user WAS created...

**I just wasn't clicking the 'refresh' button on the SQL Server Object Explorer.**

:( How embarrassing. I spent an hour+ tracking this down.

**Edit:** I see I got a negative vote. I had the same problem that the individual asking the question had and my solution was that the page needed refreshed. Although it was a stupid mistake, it's usually safe to assume that when you make a mistake, you are not the only one. My answer is a correct answer in all cases where the user didn't refresh the page, which I believe makes it a decent answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. That was the solution; go to DBContext and remove the user in the inherited class.

Before:

```
public class MyDBContext : IdentityDbContext<MyUser>
{ }
```

After:

```
public class MyDBContext : IdentityDbContext
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and none of answers here worked, eventually I found solution to that. When you have custom User table verify that in your recently created migration references that point to table AspNetUsers instead point to your custom ApplicationUser table. If not, drop database, manually modify migration file and apply changes.

Answer (score -1):

Should you be ensuring the user admin has an ID

```
if (await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(user_Admin.Id) == null)
```

should be

```
if (await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(user_Admin.Id) != null)
```

Comment: If you look at my code I add await UserManager.CreateAsync(user_Admin, "Pass4Admin"); after if expression

Comment: Ah yes, Sorry i see that. Where are you setting the ID? Does the user_admin have a Id after you call CreateAsync? Your error implies that the ID does not exist OR its null