# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager:Warning: User validation failed: InvalidUserName;InvalidEmail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I need to create a user with UserName, FirstName and LastName and Email fields. I'm using Mysql database and Pomelo package. Migration and DB update are working fine.

This code results in failure.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserAsync()
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser(
            UserName: "blablabla",
            FirstName: "blablabla",
            LastName: "blablabla",
            Email: "blablabla@gmail.com"
        );
        var successful = await mUserManager.CreateAsync(user
            , "Pasword123456#");
        if(successful.Succeeded)
            return Content("User was created", "text/html");

        return Content("User created FAILED", "text/html");
    }
}
```

The table in the database is empty

> +-----------------------+ | Tables_in_calendario  |
> +-----------------------+ | __efmigrationshistory | | aspnetroleclaims      | | aspnetroles           | | aspnetuserclaims      | |
> aspnetuserlogins      | | aspnetuserroles       | | aspnetusers
> | | aspnetusertokens      | | events                | | usuarios
> |
> +-----------------------+
> mysql> select * from aspnetusers;
> Empty set (0.00 sec)

I have no idea how to make it work.

In debug mode that is the only information I have.
[image: Debug mode]

Comment: Debug the result from `CreateAsync` - what are the details of the errors (i.e. in your `successful` variable)?

Comment: @CalC it shows the two erros, invalid name and invalid email, unfortunately no more details.

Answer (score 6):

I found out the problem.

I was overwriting Email and UserName in ApplicationUser.
This was the warning in the building.
[image]

The solution was simply removing the fields.

Answer (score 1):

In the Configure service You can do this where AppUser class is inherited from IdentityUser, you can use it directly also

```
services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>(opt =>
{              
opt.Password.RequireDigit = false;
})
```