# ASP.NET Core Identity "User validation failed: InvalidUserName" while trying to update an existing user's setting

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I have a function in my code that changes the visual theming of my website to match the selection they choose. This works without issue on my development setup, but in production (Azure Web App), it fails to actually update the database and user object with the correct theme.

The only error message or anything I get is this in the console:

```
[40m[1m[33mwarn[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager[13]
       User validation failed: InvalidUserName.
```

Which I can't seem to understand, given the code:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeThemeAsync(string theme)
    {
        bool res = Enum.TryParse(theme, out ColorTheme ct);

        if (!res)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Unable to change theme.");
        }

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}', so could not change theme.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NEW THEME: " + ct.ToString() + ", USER: " + user.UserName);
            user.UserTheme = ct;

            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
```

I clearly get the User object and then update it in the same function, without any real issues. With the Console.WriteLine there, I can verify that the correct values are being put into the function.

This is the WebsiteUser class, and I haven't made my own UserManager or any other classes (and you can tell I don't have the same issue [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55813937/microsoft-aspnetcore-identity-usermanagerwarning-user-validation-failed-inval) had):

```
public class WebsiteUser : IdentityUser
{
    // to comply with laws like COPPA and stuff like that
    [PersonalData]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    
    [PersonalData]
    public string RealName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string AboutMe { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public ColorTheme UserTheme { get; set; } = ColorTheme.None;
}

public enum Gender : byte
{
    [Display(Name = "Not set")]
    Unset = 0,
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Non-binary")]
    NonBinary = 3
}

public enum ColorTheme : byte
{
    None = 0,
    Dark = 1,
    Brown = 2,
    Blue = 3,
}
```

What is causing the `User validation failed: InvalidUserName`, and/or what differences are there between my local setup and how Azure Web App is doing this?

Comment: I tried creating a brand new user account on my website, and the new account had no issues whatsoever. Everything worked fine. Soooo it might be something with that specific account that I'll need to investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I sorted out my own issue.

In my Startup.cs file, I have this listed:

```
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._+";
```

The username of the account I was testing with included a '`@`' in it, as I had created the account before I put in the allowed characters restriction. I didn't notice any issues with this as I hadn't testing changing any of this account's settings in quite a while. So I suppose that's on me.

But at least now the issue has been resolved. I added the '`@`' character as one of the allowed characters, and now everything is working as intended!

Comment: I could delete this question as I had solved it on my own pretty quickly, but maybe there's value in keeping this up in case someone else runs into a similar issue. Unlike other questions where the "User validation failed" message popped up, the message appeared to me while I was updated an existing user, not creating a new one, so I felt the other questions didn't cover my situation much.