# c# - Adding a role to idenitity user on signup fails with foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, user-roles

I don't know if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any similar problems with solutions that helped in my case.

So I have an identity user that I want to add a role to based on which dropdown value the user chooses on signup page. I tested this part and it goes through just fine. But adding a role doesn't seem to work no matter what I try.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        bool ownerRoleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Owner");

        if (!ownerRoleExists)
        {
            var roleResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Owner"));
        }

        bool patientRoleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Patient");

        if (!patientRoleExists)
        {
            var roleResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Patient"));
        }

        bool workerRoleExists = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Worker");

        if (!workerRoleExists)
        {
            var roleResult = await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Worker"));
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new Person { UserName = Input.Email, Email = Input.Email, Name = Input.Name, LastName = Input.LastName, Address = Input.Address };
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (Input.PersonType.Equals("patient"))
                {
                    var patient = new Patient { PersonId = user.PersonId, VisitCount = 0, Number = Input.Number };
                    _context.Add(patient);
                    var patient_result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    if(patient_result > 0)
                    {
                        var result_role = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Patient");
                    }
                }
                else if(Input.PersonType.Equals("worker"))
                {
                    var worker = new Worker { PersonId = user.PersonId, WorkCode = Input.WorkCode };
                    _context.Add(worker);
                    var worker_result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                    if(worker_result > 0)
                    {
                        var result_role = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Worker");
                    }
                }
                
                _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");
            }
        }
}
```

The error I get is:

> SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AspNetUserRoles_person_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "hospital-prod", table "dbo.person", column 'person_id'.
> The statement has been terminated.

The values I get from user are correct, when I checked in the debug right before role is added so variable `user` should be correct.

Also user and patient/worker are added to the database successfully, so only the `role` is a problem.

Comment: I thing this should be tagged "Entity Framework" instead of "ASP.Net". If I understand [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21195605) correctly, you should add the user to `User` before adding it to `Person`. However, EF should be able to do everything in the right order by itself, if scaffolded correctly.

Comment: @JHBonarius I think I didn't clarify it correctly. My `User` is `Person` aka. class `Person` inherites `IdentityUser` so there is no other class above it. And it's weird because it's all added to the database correctly, which is why I don't understand why the error is of foreign key constraint type, when the user is in the database before I try to add a role.

Comment: Can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41283431) answer?

Comment: Yes, tried it but there is no error. I appreciate the help, but somehow it just doesn't want to work I guess. And it doesn't have a problem inserting Patient or Worker, which also have fk contraint. It's weird.

Comment: @JHBonarius tnx for the help. Of course it was a stupid error at the end. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out what the real problem was; and I'm going to briefly explain it, if someone else is in the same situation at some point.

The problem with adding a role in my case was that method `AddToRoleAsync(User user, String role)` accepts a User type variable not an ID, so it selects the ID by itself.

Well, I have a custom database where i already have a `person_id` column and the rules of `IdentityUser` don't allow you to remove any of the default columns and that includes the `Id`. So the problem was that that method automaticay selected a wrong `id` and I had to change the behaviour of ids' to get it to work/select the right one.